# Getting "Cannot read property 'offset' of undefined" on a touch event

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm using a color picker built in Angular, and I've been adding code to make it work on a touch screen. However, I appear to have hit a snag with a certain portion of the code, namely inside the mousedown handler. Whenever I start a touch event, I get a `Cannot read property "offset" of undefined` error.

This is also causing unresponsiveness in a desktop web browser - I am unable to click and drag the selectors smoothly.

[Plunker Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/6bZHxxiDo9fI4hEJVC1A?p=preview)

Here's the code block that gives me the error:

```
Farbtastic.prototype.mousedown = function(event) {
    // Capture mouse
    if (!this.dragging) {
      $(document).on('mousemove', this.mousemove)
        .on('mouseup', this.mouseup);
      this.dragging = true;
    }

    // Update the stored offset for the widget.
    this.offset = this.$container.offset();

    // Check which area is being dragged
    var pos = this.widgetCoords(event);
    this.circleDrag = Math.max(Math.abs(pos.x), Math.abs(pos.y)) > (this.square + 2);

    // Process
    this.mousemove(event);
    return false;
  };
```

I'm really lost on this one, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is `Farbtastic.prototype.mousedown` bound to the mouse click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use it after page is loaded:

```
$( window ).onload(function() {
  this.offset = this.$container.offset();
}).bind(this);
```

Comment: [As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document. Bind is outdated.](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) Is there another alternative?

Comment: it is another `bind()`, you are talking about `$.bind()`

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow. Can you clarify?

Comment: i am using in the answer `Function.prototype.bind()`, you linked to Jquery `bind()` method - they are different

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I thought you were talking about the same function. This does solve the error I asked about.